# File not found error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have imported the folder containing `SUPQueueConnection.h` to the project and to the project root too. Still it is showing the same error `SUPQueueConnection.h` file not found.

And we imported all such needed `.h and .m` files to the project root.
Is there any other way for doing it?

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Have you checked in your project navigator on the left whether this file is actually there?

Comment: yes,its in indexing_headers>internal bellow the project root.I tried to move it to the project root too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project navigation bar of your project check the folder you imported that it actually contains SUPQueueConnection.h file or not and if it is there try to import header file in the class in which you are using "SUPQueueConnection.h"  file.Also if project is showing SUPQueueConnection.h file then right click on this file and click "Show IN Finder" option to see where actually the file is.Make sure it is copied in project folder.

If it does not solve the problem try deleting this file and drag and drop SUPQueueConnection.h again in project directly  and make sure while copying on target your project is check marked.

Comment: Yeah,I checked it.I have added it into indexing_headers>internal.I have also tried to keep it in the project root itself outside indexing_headers.Still it is showing the same error.When I tried the 'Show In Finder 'option it showed the .h file inside 'internal'.

Comment: I am not sure how you are adding the files and what do you mean by  indexing_headers>internal.If you are copying the files directly into the folder then they will not work at all.All files should be copied using XCode Interface not by pasting it in project folders.Hope you are adding file as follows-  1-Open xcode project  2-right click on project.3- Select "add files to project name" option.4-select "copy files in to destination folder" 5-make sure taget is your project name in that dialogue box. Click Ok . Also dont forget to import SUPQueueConnection.h in the class using this .h file.

Comment: indexing_headers is a new group that I added to copy the folders containing these .h files .First we created a new group and named it as indexing_headers.Then did 'add files to projectname ' by right clicking on that group.By doing so we added two folders internal and public which contains a no of .h files which includes 'SUPQueconeection.h'.And we tried to move it to the project root also from this folder by drag and drop.

Comment: Ohh I got it.It happens only when you add group to project and while copying target is not selected as project name. Just try this out.  Delete the file from folder permanently. Now take another copy of that .h file and drag it manually in that group  again. The dialoge box which will apear has a option with check box in which the project icon is given as target.Make sure that box is selected means  the project target should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the files that aren't found are actually in your Xcode project? Make sure you can see the files somewhere in the sidebar. I've never actually tried it, but I don't think you can simply access files in the project directory root, they must be in your project. Xcode has changed since I used it last (been doing other things) but I think you can still add files by right clicking somewhere in your sidebar, also unless its changed you can add external files using a button in the file menu